# Rebuilding JSON for JSTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

It's my first meeting with JS so i have some troubles with understanding what I need to do.

I have my own REST service. I get JSON from it.
JSON looks like

```
{"list": [
{
  "id_depart": 1,
  "id_parent_depart": 1,
  "address": "Pobeda 30",
  "name_depart": "ParentDepartment",
  "name_parent_depart": "ParentDepartment"
},
{
  "id_depart": 101,
  "id_parent_depart": 1,
  "address": "gjh",
  "name_depart": "xxbxgh",
  "name_parent_depart": "ParentDepartment"
},
{
  "id_depart": 201,
  "id_parent_depart": 1,
  "address": "some addr",
  "name_depart": "department1",
  "name_parent_depart": "ParentDepartment"
},
{
  "id_depart": 203,
  "id_parent_depart": 1,
  "address": "some addr",
  "name_depart": "department2",
  "name_parent_depart": "ParentDepartment"
},
{
  "id_depart": 202,
  "id_parent_depart": 201,
  "address": "some addr",
  "name_depart": "sub-department!",
  "name_parent_depart": "department1"
}]}
```

There are an entries which have some another entries inside. It managed by "parent id's".
So there i want to create JSTree which displays this interaction.
After some hours of reading JSTree docs i understand that it use specific json format for build a tree. But I have no idea how convert my json to needed.

Also in result tree i nees to make POST requests onClick on nodes, so I need to store objects from my REST json into maybe metadata of treeObjects.

So, please, if someone can give me a little advice, it will be great! Thank you!

There a code from JSTree example

```
    $(function () {
$("#demo1").jstree({
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "data" : "A node",
                "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
            },
            {
                "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                "data" : {
                    "title" : "Long format demo",
                    "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert(jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "id")); });});
```

Comment: What's the specific JSON format you need to use?

Comment: use js to parse through your rest service json [JSON.parse() ], then as youre parsing, save the data you need from YOUR json into a new json object that is passed to the plugin. so when you parse name depart, save its value as data or title or whatever you want it saved as in the tree